# How do I make seperate Gui buttons that move an object in another scene in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine, interface, logic-bricks

So I made a maze game and I'm trying to make it so that the camera follows your avatar and I would like it to be with a GUI instead of with the keyboard. However I can't seem to figure out how to make the buttons work so that they move the character along with the camera, and if possible make it usable on a touchscreen.

Comment: Sorry  - I was trying to scroll the page and did it on the vote button.   Now I can't cancel it!  lol

Comment: The question is to how to let an object move relative to the camera or how to use virtual keys?